# Using pdf.js I'm able to read only pdf's upto 2MB and not more than that, why?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter, pdf.js

I'm getting an error after some pages are getting read

> "pdf.js:25744 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DedicatedWorkerGlobalScope': Data cannot be cloned, out of memory."

This happens only when I use a file of more than 2 MB size.

How to change that max allow file in pdf.js file?

```js
MessageHandler.prototype = {
  on: function messageHandlerOn(actionName, handler, scope) {
    var ah = this.actionHandler;
    if (ah[actionName]) {
      throw 'There is already an actionName called "' + actionName + '"';
    }
    ah[actionName] = [handler, scope];
  },
  send: function messageHandlerSend(actionName, data) {
    this.comObj.postMessage({ //console is showing error in this line
      action: actionName,
      data: data
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` . There are 2 different places you can set it in `php.ini` because the default PHP values are 2 MB for `upload_max_filesize`, and 8 MB for `post_max_size`.

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 20M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 20M
```

This changes require a server restart

Comment: I have done that change also but still having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase  upload_max_filesize and post_max_size in your php.ini (Usually you will find 2M)

Comment: I have done that change also but still having the same problem

Comment: did you restart your apache server  after changing the config ?